# WebSphere admin client connection error

Tags: java, websphere

I am getting connection error on WebSphere admin client creation process.
I read many forums but cannot fix it.

```
"Exception creating Admin Client Connection: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host "111.xxxx.." at port 8879."
```

- My dmgr port is 8879
- Host name is "111.xxxx.."
- Servers config files located c:\temp\soap.client.props, DummyClientTrustFile.jks, DummyClientKeyFile.jks

My code is below:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException;
import javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException;
import javax.management.Notification;
import javax.management.NotificationListener;
import javax.management.ObjectName;

import com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClient;
import com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory;
import com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException;

public class AdminClientConnection
{
    private AdminClient adminClient;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AdminClientConnection aClient = new AdminClientConnection();

        // Create an AdminClient
        aClient.createAdminClient();

    }

    private void createAdminClient()
    {
        // Set up a Properties object for the JMX connector attributes
        Properties clientProps = new Properties();
        clientProps.setProperty(
        AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE, AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_SOAP);
        clientProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, "111.xxxx..");
        clientProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, "8879");
        clientProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_SECURITY_ENABLED, "true");
        clientProps.setProperty(AdminClient.USERNAME, "usr");
        clientProps.setProperty(AdminClient.PASSWORD, "pass");
        clientProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_SOAP_CONFIG, "c:/temp/soap.client.props");        
        clientProps.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "c:/temp/DummyClientTrustFile.jks");
        clientProps.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "c:/temp/DummyClientKeyFile.jks");
        clientProps.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "WebAS");
        clientProps.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "WebAS");

        // Get an AdminClient based on the connector properties
        try
        {
            adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(clientProps);
        }
        catch (ConnectorException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception creating Admin Client Connection: " + e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.println("Connected to Application Server");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that `CONNECTOR_PORT` is true, `CONNECTOR_SECURITY_ENABLED` is not neccassary. Be sure that `soap.client.props` and jks files are gathered from the connector host.